# How-to do reverse DNS lookup in a virtualbox host-only network

Tags: dns, virtualbox, reverse, lookup

I have a 4 node postgres cluster running with pgpool and repmgr in a virtualbox host-only network.

The Repmgr command 'repmgr cluster show' is showing the upsteam node as not connected for all replicas. I think this is because the postgres pg_stat_replication view is not showing client_hostname.

Postgres's  documentation says for client_hostname:

"Host name of the connected client, as reported by a reverse DNS lookup of client_addr. This field will only be non-null for IP connections, and only when log_hostname is enabled."

How do I set up reverse DNS lookup in a virtualbox host-only network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such functionality exists in Virtualbox.

I ended up  building a seperate VM with Bind9 installed.

I used the following tutorial; [How To Configure BIND as a Private Network DNS Server on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-20-04)